# Custom Seekbar with empty space separator

Tags: android, seekbar

I have been trying to make custom Seekbar,but I couldn't make it properly. Please watch image and guide me how to do it.[image]

I have done up to here please watch my progress in 2 image.But I have big white space columns around Seekbar. I have followed this question David answer from [Android: SeekBar with custom drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932963/android-seekbar-with-custom-drawable) . 
[image]

Comment: Please tell what have you done so far

Comment: I designed David Medenjak answer from this question please watch it ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932963/android-seekbar-with-custom-drawable

Comment: Refer this https://www.android-examples.com/create-custom-seekbar-in-android-example-tutorial/

Comment: I am not able to design rulers with empty spaces...

Comment: You can ask your designer who can create whole background image as a strip like https://www.android-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/progress_one.png

Comment: have a look at this http://www.zoftino.com/android-seekbar-and-custom-seekbar-examples

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add custom drawable for your `Seekbar`. You need `Seekbar` background image and thumb image which you can store into **Drawable** folder.

Create custom xml as below

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <item
     android:id="@+id/SecondaryProgress"
     android:drawable="@drawable/progress_two"/>

</layer-list>
```

Use above custom xml file into `Seekbar`

```
 <SeekBar
 android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:thumb="@drawable/drag_thumb"
 android:progressDrawable="@layout/custom_seekbar_layout"
 android:max="100" />
```